# How do I use Oracle SQL to find all users in a database that start with a T but only those with a number after it?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to create a listing of all Oracle users in a database that start with the letter `T`, but also only those with a number after the `T`.

For example, `T124545` is what I'm looking for but not `TIVOLI`.

Thanks

CT

Comment: Does the number have to be directly after? Eg would Tk123 work?

Answer (score 7):

You can use regular expressions for this:

```
select * 
from dba_users
where regexp_like(username, '^T[0-9]+$');
```

Some notes:

- this requires DBA privileges (or at least `SELECT` privileges on `DBA_USERS`)
- the regular expression

  - matches a T at the beginning `^T`
  - followed by at least one digit `[0-9]+`
  - followed by the end of word `$`

Comment: Side note: connected user must have access to `dba_*` views :) +1

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer solved your problem, please consider clicking the checkbox to accept it.